# Xampp not connecting to DBForge what to do?

Tags: xampp, dbforge

Xampp not connecting to DBForge what to do?

[xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xycb6.png)

[dbforge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCrDu.png)

I clicked on xampp mysql start and opened dbforge then i clicked to new connection in dbforge but the user and root did not popped up only that window what i attached here as a dbforge picture.
I use win 10 OS, vscode, vuejs3, laravel10, git etc etc, just reinstalled OS and reinstalled all the programs and extensions, that took a while believe me, everything worked now i'm stuck here.

What i only tried was to refresh, delete localhosts..... then went to search to google. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

My answer after i checked what ports used in CMD :     netstat -anob      -- to list all established and listening ports.
netstat -anoq     -- to list all bound ports (= reserved ports)
Then in powershell :  Get-NetTCPConnection -State Bound | ForEach-Object {$p = (Get-Process -Id $*.OwningProcess);New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ "LocalPort" = $*.LocalPort; "PID" = $p.Id; "ProcessName" = $p.Name; }} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property PID, ProcessName, LocalPort
-- to see the ports in a more "organized" view.

Then i have found out i opened DBForge for SQL server instead of DBForge for MySQL, i closed DBForge for SQL server and i opened DBForge for MySQL then everything works fine. Just a blatant mistake (as usual).

[dbforgemysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egkic.png)

If you check the top left corner on the DBForge pictures you can see the first one has purple icon (DBForge for SQL server) and the second one has blue icon (DBForge for MySQL).

Comment: Hey there!

We're thrilled to hear that your question has been resolved. Remember, if you ever encounter any more questions or challenges while working with dbForge, don't hesitate to contact our support team for a speedy resolution. You can reach us by emailing support@devart.com. 

Happy coding!